# If statement - comparing datareader value to datetime

Tags: c#, if-statement, sqldatareader

I'm hoping you guys can help with a little issue I'm having. I'm getting some errors when trying to check whether a datareader value is less than a specified dateTime value and need some help.

```
DateTime feedate = new DateTime(2013,09,01);
if (rsData["M_Start"] != DBNull.Value) & (Convert.ToDateTime(rsData["M_Start"]).ToString("yyyy/mm/dd") < feedate)
```

So the above is what I have and the errors I'm getting is the 'only assignment call increment decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement' message.

I'm a bit stumped as C# is still really new to me so any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: `&` and `&&` are two different operators...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should use the logical and `&&` instead
2. You should use `DataReader.IsDBNull` instead
3. You should not compare a `DateTime` with a `String`, why do you convert it to string at all?

---

```
DateTime feedate = new DateTime(2013, 09, 01);
if (!rsData.IsDBNull(rsData.GetOrdinal("M_Start")) && (DateTime)rsData["M_Start"] < feedate)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments - this is far more logical than my approach and I'll factor it into some other stuff I'm doing.

Comment: @PipBoy: Note that you can use [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) if you want to compare only the date part. That property returns midnight of a given `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong parenthesis and 'and' operator. The code should read:

```
DateTime feedate = new DateTime(2013,09,01);
if (rsData["M_Start"] != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToDateTime(rsData["M_Start"]).ToString("yyyy/mm/dd") < feedate)
{
    // code
}
```

The `&` operator is a bit-wise or, while the `&&` operator is a logical or. The `if` statement takes a condition in parenthesis like this: `if (… condition goes here …)`.

*Note: As Tim Schmelter noted in his answer, there are several other flaws, too.*